# Position tkinter Window at Screenborder

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to position a window at the right border of the screen. This is the current code, the constants should be comprehensible I think.

```
root = Tk()
pos_x = root.winfo_screenwidth() - WINDOW_WIDTH
geometry = '{width}x{height}+{pos_x}+{pos_y}'.format(
    height=WINDOW_HEIGHT, width=WINDOW_WIDTH, pos_y=HEIGHT_OFFSET, pos_x=pos_x)
root.wm_geometry(geometry)
```

The problem is that the width of a frame seems to be the usable space without the border, which means that when I run the above code the window is not completely visible. I tried root['border'] but that returns 0 and google is surprisingly quiet about this problem.

So is there any way to get the complete size of a frame - or is this the wrong way to do this with tkinter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the window manager draws the border and does not tell you how large it is. 
You can take full control of the window by setting the [overrideredirect flag](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x9843-style-methods.htm), but that would mean you do not get a border drawn by the window manager.

But maybe [this discussion](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11291) on the Tcl'ers wiki helps, as it discusses ways to find the full window size.

Comment: Thanks, will try some of the stuff there - but now I know of at least one thing that's simpler to do even with raw Win32.. will surely be useful in some discussions ;)